# LINQ to entities exception

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to pull out an object from a DbSet with a Linq query.

I use the syntax:

```
Nation nation = nationDB.Nations.Where(c => c.ID == testNation.ID).First();
```

I get the following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Nation get_Item(Int32)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The class `Nation` has a couple of `string` fields, one `int` field (the ID) and a couple of other objects as fields.

What can the problem be?

Comment: Why do you have string "1", when ID is int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull out the integer first because there is no appropriate translation for retrieving the integer from your object `Nation` within the Linq to Entities scope:

```
int testId = testNation.ID;
Nation nation = nationDB.Nations.Where(c => c.ID == testId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ID` is of type `int` then shouldn't the line be:

```
 Nation nation = nationDB.Nations.Where(c => c.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Removed the quotes to do an `int` to `int` compare.

Answer (score 0):

so if you say " one int field (the ID) " and `.Where(c => c.ID == "1")` i think you need change to

```
.Where(c => c.ID == 1)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to correct the post. The code is actually 'Where(c => c.ID = otherNation.ID)' and I get the same error

Comment: Francesco, a single = means you are trying to assign a value.  You should use c=> c.ID == otherNation.ID.  A single = is an assignment, == means comparison.